# Using a presenter on attributes in a pivot table in Laravel

Tags: php, design-patterns, laravel, eloquent, presenter

I'm just wondering how to go about implementing the Presenter pattern for attributes inside of a pivot table? For example, consider this code (it's just an example and is not a replication of my actual code):

```
@foreach($users->comments as $comment)
 <h1>{{ $comment->title }}</h1> // calls 'title()' in CommentPresenter
 <p>{{ $comment->body }}</p> // calls 'body()' in CommentPresenter...
 <p>{{ is_null($comment->pivot->deleted_at) ? '' : '[REMOVED]' :}} // Where can I put this???
@endforeach
```

Where can I put that final attributes presenting method? Bearing in mind I also want to be able to use the inverse of this relation.

Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `newPivot` in your models and then use your own `Pivot` model. It will be treated mostly like a "normal" Eloquent model so the auto presenter package should work.

#### Comment model

```
public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists)
{
    if($parent instanceof User){
        return new CommentUserPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }
    return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
}
```

#### User model

```
public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists)
{
    if($parent instanceof Comment){
        return new CommentUserPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }
    return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
}
```

#### CommentUserPivot model

```
class CommentUserPivot extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {
    // presenter stuff
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this working. I am using a ->belongsToMany relationship on both tables, I don't know if that makes any difference? It just seems like it is never calling 'newPivot'

Comment: Have you added the `newPivot` to both models? When using `$user->comments` `newPivot` will be called in the `Comment` model

Comment: Never mind it is working correctly, thanks! My issue is though that the auto presenter package I'm using doesn't seem to be decorating the Pivot

Comment: Okay. Unfortunately I can't help you with that. Never used the package. Good luck though!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Laravel Auto Present package for this. It will allow you to implement a presenter class on the model with specific methods to override the models normal data properties. However, I don't believe this will format the data on the way in to the model (if that's what you mean by inverse).

https://github.com/ShawnMcCool/laravel-auto-presenter

Comment: I'm using this exact package, I'm wondering how to present 'pivot' attributes though rather than just the ones on the Model I'm presenting (eg. the attributes that would be on the `users_comments` table in my example, as oppose to `users` table)